# spring boot oaut2 properties

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build an app that implements google oauth2 authentication with spring boot. I'm following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) from the oficials spring web page. I have troubles to figure out what configuration I need to connect with google. This is the one that is used to connect with facebook (yml format):

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 233668646673605
      clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

I allready have my clientId and clientSecret from google api console (also configured my redirect url), but I have no idea where the rest of the properties comes from. I'm aware that there is a java api to authenticate with google but I would prefer to do it with spring tools if posible.

I would apreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could figured out where they are. In the google api console, after create your app, go to edit your app credentials and click in download json. All it is needed is there. In my case is like this.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: MY_CLIENTID
      clientSecret: MY_SECRET
      accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: email
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

Note that you also need to specify a scope property to make authentication api happy (yeah!!)